# Errors in converting float64 column to datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert float64 type to datetime format.

As an example 20181219.0 data, I want is as 2018-12-19

I have tried common code;

df1['ACT_DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['ACT_DATE1'], format='%Y/%m/%d')

But, what I get is 
1970-01-01 00:00:00.020181219

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df1['ACT_DATE1'].astype(int).astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')` ?

Comment: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Answer (score 1):

First obviously problem here are some missing values, which are converted to `NaT` for missing datetimes.

Tested in pandas 0.25.0 and there is no problem with `.0` values only necessary specify format of datetimes - `%Y%m%d`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ACT_DATE1' : [20181219.0, np.nan]})

df1['ACT_DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['ACT_DATE1'], format='%Y%m%d') 
print (df1)
   ACT_DATE1
0 2018-12-19
1        NaT
```

If not working and is necessary remove missing values and converting to integer:

```
dates = df1['ACT_DATE1'].dropna().astype(int)
df1['ACT_DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y%m%d')
```